# plan a effective algorithm to check who is online to the web site, with PHP and AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

i need some help to plan an effective algorithm to check who is online to my web site, with PHP and AJAX.

**(i dont need you to write any sourse to me!!)**

the biggest problem is how to know when the member get off.

in the end, it will be a list of online members that alwayes update, like what facebook have.

Comment: Does it specifically need to be AJAX? If not, just [store your sessions in a database](http://shiflett.org/articles/storing-sessions-in-a-database) and then your "online users" are the users for whom you have a timestamp in the last ten minutes (or whatever cutoff value you want).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a timestamp, with PHP you can do strtotime("now");

You add that timestamp to the user's table in MySQL, or their session info.  Then, you update that timestamp whenever the user changes pages or accesses the site.  To determine if the user is offline, you can remove the timestamp when the user logs off, and if the user just exits without logging off, you would just compare the timestamp to the current time.

For example, you could look to see if 15 minutes has passed by checking the timestamp variable like this:

```
if($timestamp <= strtotime("-15 minutes")) echo "User is offline";
```